# incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to LifecycleOwner

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-room, android-livedata

[MainActivity cannot be converted to LifecycleOwner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyNCM.png)
I used this as LiveCycle Owner, but it is rejected and I got an error as you see in the picture. 
I work on `Api 25` and I this the problem may be related to this version
This is info about my sdk

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
```

This is my code:

```
private void retrieveTasks() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Actively retrieving the tasks from the DataBase");
    // Extract all this logic outside the Executor and remove the Executor
    // Fix compile issue by wrapping the return type with LiveData
    LiveData<List<TaskEntry>> tasks = mDb.taskDao().loadAllTasks();
    // Observe tasks and move the logic from runOnUiThread to onChanged
    tasks.observe(this, new Observer<List<TaskEntry>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<TaskEntry> taskEntries) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Receiving database update from LiveData");
            mAdapter.setTasks(taskEntries);
        }
    });
}
```

I put LiveData dependencies in my `Gradle`

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"
```

If anyone knows the reason for the problem, let me know please

Comment: What does your MainActivity extend?

Comment: MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskAdapter.ItemClickListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments and Activities in Support Library 26.1.0 and later already implement the LifecycleOwner interface by default

but in version 25 you need to implement LifecycleOwner interface
for example

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LifecycleOwner {
    private LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }
}
```

Source : [Handling lifecycles with lifecycle-aware components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

Answer (score 2):

As you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#26-1-0) the `LifecycleOwner` was added in support library `26.1.0`. Easiest way to fix your issue would be upgrading your support library version.

Comment: I have no space in my computer to upgrade my support library version, so I need the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Upgrading to androidx support libraries fixed the issue. 
Choose inside Android Studio: Refactor -> Migrate to android x